# How to get rotated rectangle’s corner coordinates?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to get a corner coordinates of rotated rectangle. Then, create a polygon with these coordinates.

So far, I tried to use Rectangle.nortwest, southeast etc. functions but it gives me coordinates before rotation.

[image: Rotated rectangle and created polygon picture]

Here’s my code: [Cesium Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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)

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var tl = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(43.92666513491127,37.413199590790164,0);
var tr = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(44.142734829047264,37.413199590790164,0);
var bl = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(43.92666513491127,37.29166038783867,0);
var br = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(44.142734829047264,37.29166038783867,0);

tl = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(tl);
tr = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(tr);
bl = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(bl);
br = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(br);

var cartoArr = [bl, br, tr, tl];

var convRect = viewer.entities.add({
  rectangle : {
    coordinates: Cesium.Rectangle.fromCartesianArray(cartoArr),
    material: Cesium.Color.PURPLE.withAlpha(0.7),
    rotation: -46.22552065940672
  }
});


var rect = convRect.rectangle.coordinates._value;

var northeast = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Cesium.Rectangle.northeast(rect));
var northwest = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Cesium.Rectangle.northwest(rect));
var southwest = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Cesium.Rectangle.southwest(rect));
var southeast = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Cesium.Rectangle.southeast(rect));

var cartes = [northwest, southwest, southeast, northeast];

var polygonFirst = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon : {
      hierarchy : cartes,
      material: Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(0.8),
    }
});

polygonFirst.polygon.stRotation = -46.22552065940672;

viewer.zoomTo(convRect);
```

Any idea about converting rectangle to polygon?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate rotated positions using Matrix operations.

Here's [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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)
[image]

Comment: Can you edit this answer to explain a little more about what the math does here, and copy the relevant changes to include in the answer here?